# Tri Boot on an iMac

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, mac, refit

I have a 2013 iMac (desktop) which is running OS X Mavericks, Windows 8 and Ubuntu Raring.

I am using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to do the initial boot up but there are a few problems with this setup:

1. it takes a long time (maybe 30 seconds) for rEFInd to start up (I understand that this is the fault of some Apple scanning, and not rEFInd).
2. rEFInd is unable to launch Windows (it hangs with the windows logo). I must hold `alt` on startup to select booting off that drive.
3. Ubuntu's grub lists all the OSes **again**, which annoys me... especially since it is unable to launch either OS X or Windows if they are selected.

which basically feels like I have 3 layers of booters, and if I want to boot into an OS I need to remember which layer to use.

The ideal setup would be to just hold the alt key on startup, which would give me a choice of OS to startup. It's not as pretty as rEFInd, but it would be conceptually simpler and (hopefully) avoid the startup wait. But Ubuntu's grub is not in the list: it only has OS X, OS X recovery, WINDOWS and any external drives I have connected.

**How do I add grub to the Mac boot list, and how do I make it the default?** *And how can I name the options? I'm actually Quad booting with Debian and I'd need a way to distinguish Linux flavours.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, regarding the 30-second delay, see the [rEFInd documentation on this subject.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#sluggish) The solution that seems to work best is to create a small (~100MiB) HFS+ partition for rEFInd and install rEFInd to it with the `--ownhfs {device_filename}` option to `install.sh`.

Concerning Windows, please post technical details of your partitions and Windows installation mode. In particular, show the output of both `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` in Ubuntu. (You may need to install `gdisk` via `sudo apt-get install gdisk`.) If you have more than one disk, repeat those commands for each of them. Post the results to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and provide the URL or edit your question to include the output. In the second case, add four spaces to the start of each line to preserve formatting.

Another comment on Windows: Starting with Windows 8, it's become much easier to install Windows in EFI mode. Googling on keywords produces many hits on the subject, but [this one](http://thetecherra.com/2012/12/11/tutorial-install-windows-8-on-a-mac-via-native-efi/) looks like a decent tutorial. Using EFI-mode booting for all your OSes will solve any number of problems. Unfortunately, Apple and Microsoft don't seem to be doing much to make it easier.

Concerning GRUB: It shouldn't be necessary to use GRUB at all. If you install an [EFI filesystem driver](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html) for whatever filesystem holds your Linux kernel, you can bypass GRUB entirely for booting Linux; rEFInd will show your Linux kernels and enable you to boot them directly.

Comment: thanks! I'll look at creating an HFS+. `gdisk` output here https://gist.github.com/fommil/9729582

Comment: Your `/dev/sdb` is Linux-only, but has a hybrid MBR. Linux doesn't use the MBR side of a hybrid MBR, so this is pointless; you can use `gdisk` to convert it back to a conventional protective MBR by using the `n` option on the `gdisk` experts' menu. It's not clear to me why rEFInd can't boot Windows. That might be clearer if you were to post the `fdisk` output.

Comment: thanks @Rod, I have made it a protective MBR and updated the gist (`fdisk` of `/dev/sda` at the top).

Comment: ok, weirdness. Installing to a separate HFS+ means that OS X no longer appear in the rEFInd list! (but it does start up fast) Installing to the OS X root drive is also fast, but now the icons for Debian / Ubuntu are replaced with a generic EFI logo and I can only tell what they are from the raw filenames. Windows still doesn't start from rEFInd and, worse, has disappeared from the alt-key bootup

Comment: Try hitting the Esc key in rEFInd to see if OS X reappears. If it does, using the `scan_delay` option in `refind.conf` may help. I don't know why the Debian and Ubuntu icons would have changed. Unfortunately, there's a lot of subtlety in multi-booting, especially on a Mac. My usual advice on Macs is to not even try to boot more than two OSes; instead, use virtualization for anything beyond OS #2 (and often even beyond OS #1).

Comment: I got the OSX booter back by installing on the OSX root. Since refind already found the Linux kernels, I just deleted the grub binaries. But the Windows issue is concerning... now it has disappeared from the mac fallback booter. How can I get it back there at least? (and is it possible to do the same for the grub images?)

Comment: My best guess is that something has overwritten the Windows boot loader in the MBR or in the Windows boot partition. Using a Windows recovery tool may be required. Alternatively, converting it to boot in EFI mode might work (and might be better in the long run, although it's tricky to do and might not work at all). See [here](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) for information on that approach, or ask for help on an Apple forum; Windows booting issues on Macs aren't really what this site is about.

Comment: I reinstalled Windows, but only after formatting my drive and discovering that I needed to set the windows partition to hybrid mode. Something had changed it and I could have avoided a reinstall if I realised in time. Delayed scanning also fixes the osx problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: it's looking sweet now with the minimal theme. One niggling thing: is it possible to disable the text notification "refind is waiting before scanning"? It's a bit ugly to be presented with it on every startup, especially since the menu selection is so cool.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that notification is hard-coded and can't be disabled -- at least, not short of recompiling the software yourself. If you're up for that, look for the message in `main.c` and uncomment the line in which it appears.